# Integer view format in Matlab

Tags: matlab, format, digit

I have a matlab code that its output will print as an input text file for other program. But the numbers format is important in input file of my desired program it should start with 0. and then the number. For example, I want to format the output of Matlab program from the **3.00E+03 to 0.30E+04**. 
Can anyone between you experts kindly help me?

Many tanx

Comment: Please provide some more information of the range of your data. All integers, positive, negative, etc.

Comment: All of them are positiv integers. Their range is between 900000 to 1980000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the reference for fprintf. You can find it in the format specifier:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Probably the format you desire is not available in MATLAB so you can create your own!

First use log 10 to obtain the power (assuming):
Assuming a number X.

```
% Number to convert    
X = 3867;
% Number of decimals after comma
n = 2;

% Calculation of the power to print
power = floor(log10(X))+1;
% Calculation of the decimals (correctly rounded)
decimals = round(X/10^(power-n));

% The format of fprintf. 0. is static, %d represents the printed decimals, %+0.3d represents the power. + denoting the sign, 0. denoting padding with zeros, 3 denoting the number of characters printed (if less characters in the power padded with zeros).

fprintf('0.%dE%+0.3d',decimals,power)
```

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: It works exactly and was useful for me as well, Lots of tanx :)